# Do Microsoft's imagex/dism have the equivalent of wimlib's --delta-from?

Tags: dism, mdt

For pushing small changes to an existing wim image, you can significantly reduce network traffic by using the previous wim file as a base wim and a file that contains only the "changes" as the main wim.

[wimlib](https://wimlib.net/) is an open source library for playing with wim files, and it has an awesome feature to make doing creating these "changes-only" wim files. You just do:

```
.\wimlib-imagex.exe capture <folder_to_capture> <output.wim> --delta-from=<base.wim>
```

The result is a tiny output.wim that has only metadata and the files that differ from base.wim. You can then apply the image, even with Microsoft's tools, as so:

```
Expand-WindowsImage -ImagePath <output.wim> -Index 1 -ApplyPath `
<output_folder> -SplitImageFilePattern <base.wim>
```

**Two questions:**

1. Do Microsoft's first-party imagex/dism tools offer any way to get
   the same functionality (just so I can avoid adding another
   dependency if possible)? They offer splitting an existing wim into pieces, but I don't see anything to help create a "delta" type wim from a folder/wim and a base wim.
2. If not, are there any issues I should be aware with when using
   wimlib? My use case is capturing and applying images via Microsoft's
   Deployment Toolkit. I see wimlib does not support NTFS extended
   attributes yet, but MDT does not capture those as far as I can tell.